# A question about flagging a post as spam

Tags: support, flagging, down-votes, community-user, spam

I have noticed that whenever I flag a question as spam, it immediately receives a downvote. I guess the [Community user](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) casts the down vote.

My question is, if my flag eventually gets declined will the downvote be removed from the question or will it stay irrespective of whatever happens to my flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the flag is declined, the downvotes will be removed. See this part of the FAQ [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> Each red flag, **during its validity**, carries an implicit downvote from the Community user, which does not affect the flagger’s reputation.

(emphasis mine)

The last part may be confusing, but normally, downvoting an answer costs 1 rep; this is not the case for spam-flagging an answer.

Comment: But it does not explicitly say that the downvote will be removed. I mean the block quote portion.

Comment: After it's declined, it's not valid anymore.

Comment: Yes understood. The block quote says "as long as the flag is valid, the downvote stays". IMO it could have been more explicit in saying that " downvotes are removed as well when the flags become invalid".

Comment: The post is already quite long, that's probably why they keep things brief.

Comment: That's ok. Their message is well conveyed.